# C# JSON deserialize Dynamic variables

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to Json and i'm trying to parse the following example coming from one supplier:

```
{
  "Nodes": [ "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "IDxx" ],
  "Results": {
    "ID1": {
      "ID2": {
        "value1": "example1",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      },
      "ID3": {
        "value1": "example2",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      }
    },
    "ID3": {
      "ID1": {
        "value1": "example3",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      },
      "ID2": {
        "value1": "example4",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      },
      "ID3": {
        "value1": "example5",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried these line to access Value1 but it always returns null:

```
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonData);
    var data = ((JObject)json.Results).Children().ToArray();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var childss = item.Children().ToArray();

        foreach (var item2 in childss)
        {
            var sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(item2.ToString());
            string hmm = sub.value1;
        }
    }
```

would anyone have an idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Children` will always return the children of the root object. You need to use the Value property and then ask for its children. This code should work:

```
var data = ((JObject)json.Results).Children().ToArray();

foreach (JProperty item in data)
{
    var childss = item.Value.Children().ToArray();

    foreach (JProperty item2 in childss)
    {
        dynamic sub = item2.Value;
        string hmm = sub.value1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ID2
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ID3
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ID1
{
    public ID2 ID2 { get; set; }
    public ID3 ID3 { get; set; }
}

public class ID12
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ID22
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ID33
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ID32
{
    public ID12 ID1 { get; set; }
    public ID22 ID2 { get; set; }
    public ID33 ID3 { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public ID1 ID1 { get; set; }
    public ID32 ID3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> Nodes { get; set; }
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}
```

And then something like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonData);
```

You will get everything in the root object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that variables' names IDxx are dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

The JObjects are already dynamic and deserialized, so you don't need to re-serialize them and deserialize them again.

Your input structure has another layer of objects that you seem to be skipping over. If you wanted the `value1` value from `Results.ID1.ID2`, for example, you'll need to dig a little deeper:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonData);
var data = ((JObject)json.Results).Properties().Values().Cast<JObject>().ToArray();

foreach (var item in data)
{
    var childss = item.Properties().Values().ToArray();
    foreach (dynamic item2 in childss)
    {
        string hmm = item2.value1;
        Console.WriteLine(hmm);
    }
}
```

You can clean up the syntax significantly, though:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(JsonData);
List<string> value1s = json.SelectTokens("Results.*.*.value1").Values()
    .Select(t => t.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
        string test = "{   \"Nodes\": [ \"ID1\", \"ID2\", \"ID3\", \"IDxx\" ],   \"Results\": {     \"ID1\": {       \"ID2\": {         \"value1\": \"example1\",         \"value2\": \"exempleHexa\"       },       \"ID3\": {         \"value1\": \"example2\",         \"value2\": \"exempleHexa\"       }     },     \"ID3\": {       \"ID1\": {         \"value1\": \"example3\",         \"value2\": \"exempleHexa\"       },       \"ID2\": {         \"value1\": \"example4\",         \"value2\": \"exempleHexa\"       },       \"ID3\": {         \"value1\": \"example5\",         \"value2\": \"exempleHexa\"       }     }   } }";
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test);
        Console.WriteLine("test output" + obj.Nodes[0]);
```

Just access the data by passing the index of the array they are in like `obj.Nodes[0]` and so on.